# Fastest place to get 120 film developed?

Tags: film, developing, medium-format

What is the fastest place to get 120 film developed? Preferably mail order because the pharmacies/walmarts/targets in my area don't process film. Also I'd like it to be under 10 dollars to develop only and send back negatives.

Comment: Well that depends entirely on where you are! In Bristol, UK, a place called Photographique will do 120 C41 in an hour, and that's only a mile or so away from me. So if you're in a city you should be able to find somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing beats a local shop when it comes to speed.
I can have my film developed in 1 hour if I want/need to in my local shop. And they know their business, not doing some nonsense with my film.

I only send a b&w film to one of the big services and it was a disaster with a greenish color cast and quite expensive.

Assuming the location in your profile is real, I had myself a google for "bridgeton new jersey film develop", with the following results:

- [Indie Photo Lab](http://www.indiephotolab.com/): according to their [price list (scroll down to "develop only")](http://www.indiephotolab.com/film-processing-2/) 120 film with 8-16 exposures costs:

  - color: 5$
  - b&w: 7$
- [Photo Lounge](http://www.myphotolounge.com/): I could not find a price list, but there are some turnaround time estimates [on their processing site](http://www.myphotolounge.com/pages/film-processing):

  - C41 color: M-F in by 11am done 4:30pm
  - b&w: typically 2 business days
- [colourworks](http://www.colourworks.com/): not as fancy a website, but with all the important information in [one place](http://www.colourworks.com/film_processing.htm):

  - C 41 color: 4,80$ per roll in 24 hours
  - E 6 color: 8,00$ per roll in 2-4 hours normally, possibly 1 hour
  - b&w: 8,00$ per roll in 24 hours

Great, google being stupid google they are all around Philadelphia, PA, which looks like a 1 hour drive from where you are. Not sure if driving there is an option, but maybe you can also send them your film and they can send it back, being so close, the turnaround time should be rather short. I guess giving them a call or email cannot hurt.

Digging a bit closer to home, I found this on usdirectory.com:

```
Eckerd Express Photo
FILM DEVELOPING
1070 N Pearl St, Bridgeton, NJ 08302
```

Not sure if they still exist, go take a look or try to call them.

All other results there within a 30 mile radius are either Walmart, Sam's club or Rite Aid, which according to you do not process film.

I think it's rather strange that they do not develop film, because it's usually sent to some huge lab anyway.